When I deploy a BERT model using Flask API, an error occurs like this. How can I fix it?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\S\master\BERT\app.py", line 2, in 
import torch
File "C:\Users\LENOVO THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch_init_.py", line 148, in 
raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\LENOVO THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
